# How to Show Div on Mobile Only and Hide from Desktop

Tags: css, mobile

Using wordpress: How would I show the particular div on mobile and hide it on desktop users i tried the following:

```
.element {display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.element{ display: inline;}
}
```

I tried the code here and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/m8yh9nL5/
but when using it on wordpress its not working.?

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit late, but hey it worked for me. I had the exact same issue. Wrote a similar snippet which worked outside wordpress. But when I wanted to use it in Wordpress it didn't work (I still don't know WHY) however I fixed it by adding `!important` after the `display: none` etc.

For example:
`display: none !important;`

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

what does the markup of your wordpress site looks like?

Have you included the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>`
this is what my site is using...

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
    window.onresize = function()
    {
       if(document.body.clientWidth < 600)
       {
           //Code to hide your element
       }
    }
```

Comment: `//code to hide` - meaning the div .element will i only put the .element??

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.